# flyway maven can't find oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: oracle, maven, flyway, ojdbc

I'm trying to run flyway from maven with the following maven plugin configuration and this command:
mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=/myfolder/flyway.conf flyway:info

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>18.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

but I get the following exception:
can anyone please help me figuring this out. I couldn't find any discussion about similar problem anywhere.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.2.4:info (default-cli) on project tms: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver => Check whether the jar file is present -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.2.4:info (default-cli) on project tms: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver => Check whether the jar file is present

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.2.4:info (default-cli) on project tms: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver => Check whether the jar file is present

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver => Check whether the jar file is present
```

Answer (score 0):

The OJDBC dependency is not in the Maven Central Repository but in the http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/ repository.
You have to configure this repository in your Maven settings.xml file

Comment: we use our internal repo that has ojdbc8-18.3.0.0, and I confirmed that it's downloaded to my .m2 folder.